# Viewing compiled PHP files

Tags: php

Hi i have been given a php file which i believe is compiled

The source looks like this 
[image]

Can i decompile this file to see the source?

Comment: try http://www.techtalkz.com/programming/142-dezender-php-decoder-php-decompiler-decode-zend-ioncube-sourceguardian.html

Comment: PHP-files (or the whole PHP-language itself) are not being compiled but interpreted (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) - So it seems you're dealing with something else here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking at a PHP file compiled with an obfuscator such as `ZendGuard` or `IonCube` though by the looks of the code on the picture I don't recognize the code structure as being part of either of them.

Might also be a simple corrupted file but don't exclude 3rd-party obfuscators.

Have you tried executing the script on the server? Most of the obfuscators will actually complain about a missing server module if its not present on the server itself to decode the script. Not true for all of the obfuscators though.

Answer (score 0):

Php files are not compiled. They get interpreted during execution. Looks like your file is somehow corrupted. Try to redownload it.